# Why am I getting "IndexError: tuple index out of range"?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

When I run this code I receive an error at line 53 "IndexError: tuple index out of range." When I try changing the Out.shape functions from 1 and 2 to 0 and 1, this error goes away but the LSTM model doesn't work since it requires a 3-D array, and with 0 and 1, I am inputting a 2-D array? How can I fix this and why am I having this issue? Thank you!

```
    import numpy
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers import Dropout
    from keras.layers import LSTM
    from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
    from keras.utils import np_utils

    #Load in text file and read it into raw_text data.
    filename = "berkuttext.txt"
    raw_text = open(filename).read()
    #Convert all text to lowercase to reduce the vocabulary network
    #needs to learn.
    raw_text = raw_text.lower()

    #Create set of distinct characters from text.
    chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
    #Convert characters into unique integers.
    charsToInt = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

    #Print each character in text and the integer assigned to it.
    print charsToInt

    #Find the total amount of characters, and total amount of
    #unique characters and print the result.
    nChars = len(raw_text)
    nVocab = len(chars)
    print "Total Characters:", nChars
    print "Total Vocab:", nVocab

    #Preparing dataset of input to output pairs, encoded as integers.
    seqLength = 10
    dataIn = []
    dataOut = []
    for i in range(0, nChars - seqLength, 1):
        seqIn = raw_text[i:i + seqLength]
        seqOut = raw_text[i + seqLength]
        dataIn.append([charsToInt[chars] for chars in seqIn])
        dataOut.append(charsToInt[seqOut])
    nPatterns = len(dataOut)
    print "Total Patterns:  ", nPatterns

    #Reshape (reshape what??) into array of integers.
    In = numpy.reshape(dataIn, (nPatterns, seqLength), 1)
    #Normalize array of intgers into floats between 0 and 1.
    In = In / float(nVocab)
    #One hot encode the output variable, array only 0's and an 1
    #representing the correct output variable.
    Out = np_utils.to_categorical(dataOut)

    #Define the LSTM model
    model = Sequential()
```

Line below is where the error occurs --->>>>

```
    model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(In.shape[2], In.shape[1]), return_sequences=True))                     
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(256))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(Out.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

    #Define the checkpoint, which records all network weights to file
    #each time an improvement in loss is observed at the end of the epoch.
    filepath = "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4d}.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
    callbacksList = [checkpoint]

    #Fitting data to the LSTM model.
    model.fit(In, Out, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacksList)
```

Comment: Probably `len(In.shape) < 3` so `In.shape[2]` is raising an `IndexError`

Comment: So how would you recommend I fix this? Sorry, I'm just starting to get into neural networks, I appreciate the help! @MarcosModenesi

Comment: Also I checked and len(In.shape) is indeed equal to 2. So you are correct. I'm not sure how to fix this though? @MarcosModenesi

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by messing around with the numpy.reshape function. Thank you for pointing that out! @MarcosModenesi

Comment: Is a bidimentional array what you expect `In` to be? I guess you could fix it reshaping your array, or not assuming its three-dimentional or above. To answer that I would have to be a) familiar with neural networks and b) familiar with the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yup, I fixed it by reshaping it. Thanks for pointing out where the error was though!